# embed commands in pdf link

Tags: url, pdf, hyperlink, command

I want to embed PDF commands in links in a PDF document.  For example, I have a "CLOSE" link that should close the PDF onClick.  Or a "SEARCH" link that will bring up the search box onClick.  Is this possible with url key words in the link or is there some script that I need to embed on the onClick event handler?  If it's a script, what commands are available to me and in what language?

I'm generating the PDF dynamically with xalan by combining XSLT-FO and my xml data file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found that XSLT-FO doesn't support adobe commands such as close, search or print.  I ended up using iText to add these actions during post-processing after the PDF has been generated.